# Testing the .json response of a regular Grails controller

Tags: json, unit-testing, grails, geb

I am attempting to run Unit tests on my controllers, but testing for the '.json' result, not just the regular result.  For example, instead of User/Index, I want to test the User/Index.json result.  How do I do this in a Unit (or geb?) test?

These are very basic controllers.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add all the details with what you have attempted?

Answer (score 3):

if your controller returns a value as `JSON` then you can access this value in your controllerSpec using the controller.response.json.valueYouWantToAccess

e.g. 
if the return value is

```
([statusCode: 1, statusMessage: message(code:"success.message" , default: success")] as JSON)
```

then in your `controllerSpec` you can access it like this:

```
controller.response.json.statusMessage
```